# Django: when I try to access localhost, it displays an empty object list

Tags: python, django

Please help me. When I trying to access `http://127.0.0.1:8000/myblog/` It display empty object list.

Here is my template file.

```
{% extends "base_entries.html" %}
{% block title %}{{block.super}} | Latest entries{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
{% for entry in object_list %}
<h2>{{entry.title}}</h2>
<p>Published on {{entry.pub_date|date:"F j, Y"}}</p>
{% if entry.excerpt_html %}
{{entry.excerpt|safe}}
{% else %}
 {{entry.body_html|truncatewords_html:"50"|safe}}
{% endif %}
<p><a href="{{entry.get_absolute_url}}">Read Full entry</a></p>
{% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

this is my `entries.py` url. I have included into main urls.py

```
`from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
 from myblog.models import Entry

 entry_info_dict = {
    'queryset': Entry.objects.all(),
    'date_field': 'pub_date',
 }
 urlpatterns = patterns('django.views.generic.date_based',
     (r'^$',
     'archive_index',entry_info_dict,
     'blog_entry_archive_index'),

 )`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `archive_index` generic view, the default name of the template variable is `latest`, not `object_list`.

[archive_index documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/generic-views/#django-views-generic-date-based-archive-index)